# Не могу настроить правильное отображение и запись данных из выпадающего списка в Access 2016

Tags: ms-access

Всем привет!

У меня есть две таблицы. Первая ПриуроченноеСобытие и вторая Награда. Они связаны связью один ко многим, т.е. одна запись из первой таблицы соответствует многим записям во второй.

Ключевое поле под названием Код первой таблицы(ПриуроченноеСобытие) имеет тип поля счетчик, а ключевое поле второй таблицы(Награды) Событие числовой.

Я создал форму на основе второй таблицы. Полю Событие соответствует окно с выпадающим списком Событие.

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы в выпадающем списке мне показывались значения, из поля Название события, а в таблицу шло значение из поля Код.

Пробовал решить это используя в качестве "Источника строк" запрос, но запутался.

Подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему?